# Declaring an object with a parameterized constructor inside another class C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, constructor

I wish to have an object of one class contained inside a different class.

class A contained inside class B as in the simple example below.

The problem is that class A only has a parametrized constructor.

Is there another way to do declare the class A object in class B without having to use a pointer to class A ?

```
class A
{
    public:
        A(int var1, int var2);
    private:
        //...
};

class B
{
    public:
        B();
    private:
        A  a;      // Compiler error 
        A* a_ptr; // This will of course work fine. We can create a new A object with parameters any time using the a_ptr
};
```

Comment: I guess this compiler error is self sufficient to understand what you can do in this case:  ---constructor for 'B' must explicitly initialize the member 'a' which does not have a default constructor

Comment: Unfortunately, you are misrepresenting or misinterpreting your problem.   `B` having a member of type `A` doesn't cause a compilation error, unless the definition of `A` is not visible to the compiler (e.g. from a previously included header).     A compilation error will be the result if the constructor of `B` attempts to construct an `A` using a constructor that `A` does not have.    Change the definition of `B`s constructor to (assuming not inline in the definition of class `B`)  to  `B::B() : A (2,3) {}` and it will compile.   (I've picked values of `2` and `3` randomly to make the point).

Comment: @Peter you mean `B::B() : a (2,3) {}` (*a* not *A*) because *B* does not inherits *A* and you want to give arguments to constructor of *A* for *a*

Answer (score 0):

> A  a;      // Compiler error

except if the constructor of *B* explicitly calls the constructor of *A* with required arguments (e.g. `B() : a(an_int, an_int) {...}`), that requests a constructor without parameter or where all parameters have default value, but you do not have that constructor, only a constructor requiring 2 *int*

> Is there another way to do declare the class A object in class B without having to use a pointer to class A ?

you do not *declare* but *define* / instantiate a new instance of *A* each time you instantiate a new instance of *B*

Note you can create later the instance of A without using a pointer as with *a_ptr* having for instance

```
std::vector<A> a;
```

and when you know the instance of *A* you need doing for instance

```
a.push_back(A(an-int, an-int));
```

but the fact you want only one instance is not visible in the definition of *a* (out of a welcome comment)

Comment: why DVs ? can you help me to understand them ?

Comment: Of course, I understand the compiler error. It's trying to create an object of class A by using a non-parametrized constructor which doesn't exist. How can I do this without having to use pointers?  I can write A a(int var1, int var2); Inside class B

Comment: @Engineer999 as I say in my answer you need to explicitly calls the only existing constructor of *A* in *B* constructor. You cannot declare/define *A* constructor in class *B*

Comment: I can use initializer lists with the constructor of class B to initialize the object A a with parameters. This works. However, if I don't know the values to pass to the class A constructor at the time of class B's construction, then it looks like I have no choice but to use pointers?

Comment: @Engineer999 while you don't know the values to pass yes you cannot instantiate the class, but you can use a vector for instance to create it later, I edited my answer

Comment: @Engineer999 is my answer ok for you ?